# Who gave Harry the Nimbus 2000?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*, who gave Harry the Nimbus 2000 broomstick?

Comment: see also: [Why was McGonagall allowed to give Harry the Nimbus 2000?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7379/5184)

Comment: yeah i think this has been covered extensively between the 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a gift from Professor Minerva McGonagal.

She gifted it to him after he made it(/got selected) to the Griffindor Quidditch team.

It was she who spoke to Dumbledore about softening the rules for letting Harry into the team, and also it's a gift from her.

Note: Professor McGonagal is the Head of the Griffindor house at Hogwarts.

According to the Harry Potter wikia:

> Harry made the team, remarkable for a First year, and became the
>   youngest Seeker in a century. McGonagall made arrangements for Harry
>   to have a Nimbus 2000, the fastest broomstick of the time, for use
>   during games and practice

However, it is unclear whether she has gifted it to him, or whether it was provided to him by the school (after Minerva talked to Dumbledore about the rules).

Comment: @AmanRaizada Glad that my answer helped you :)

Comment: Actually it did, thanks.

Comment: Where in the books is this? I see the wiki, and all, but do they cite a source on that?

Comment: @TheNate It is not in the books, so it isn't a canon source :)   Given the fact that McGonagall took the pains of talking to Dumbledore, and her excitement towards the team, that's a fair inference to make IMO

Comment: Fair enough. I interpreted that as an anonymous gift from his furry godfather, so I was curious if I missed something that precluded that possibility.

Comment: @TheNate _I interpreted that as an anonymous gift from his furry godfather_:  Fair interpretation to make ;)