# How well are professors paid at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, economics

Just kind of a curious question that came to mind while looking at [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115725/47678) about who gifted Harry the Nimbus 2000 (a fairly expensive broom at the time, I would imagine) which says it was McGonagal who gave it to him (although apparently through the school, while reading more and the linked non-dupe question).

Although I suppose she didn't pay for it herself, it still got me thinking... Compared to other professions in the wizarding world, how well are the professors paid? I cannot recall anything in either the books (which I have not read in some time) or the films, where they ever talk about their salary.

Comment: it appears to be typical to what a muggle teacher would make, enough, but not too much, because slugghorn is always looking for more money to increase his personal comforts which he cant afford normally on his teachers salary

Comment: Slughorn does demand a pay rise in The Half Blood Prince, so I cannot imagine it's too much

Comment: Slughorn would demand more money anyway, he is an opportunistic kind of character that takes what he can get his hands on, so what if he has to break a few little rules... he must be the quintessential Slytherin :P

Comment: Enough to persuade new DADA teachers to take the job, year after year, despite the appalling track record of former candidates.

Comment: @alexwlchan - That's what was keeping me from saying "not a lot", despite the fact Slughorn demands a raise. But I suppose there could be a certain amount of prestige in the position?

Comment: @DangerZone I don't think prestige alone persuades people to take a job with a history of killing, maiming or seriously injuring previous applicants. I think that's a large paycheck. :-)

Comment: @alexwlchan - Yes, definitely not alone. I would have a **very** hard time believing anyone would take that position for the status.

Comment: To be fair, it didn't really persuade DADA teachers to take the job. Even by *Chamber of Secrets* Lockhart (the idiot) was (in Hagrid's words) the *only* man for the job. Lupin had pretty much no other choice and was a friend of Dumbledore's. Moody was doing Dumbledore a favour - one year only. Umbridge inserted herself in for political reasons and the only reason she could was nobody else would have it. And Snape, of course, was the guy on the inside

Comment: @Himarm muggle teacher salaries vary wildly, based on subject, gender, experience, geographical location, age range taught, school prestige, etc. "Teacher" could net you $20,000 a year or upwards of $200,000.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Slughorn isn't bowled over by his salary even after his raise. When Harry takes Felix Felicis and runs into Slughorn before Aragog's burial, he explains what he's doing and Slughorn realises there's an opportunity to collect some venom and so goes down to Hagrid's, gets drunk and eventually hands over the memory. While he's talking himself into this we get:

> '... seems an awful waste not to collect it ... might get a hundred Galleons a pint ... to be frank, my salary is not large ...'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.450 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 22, *After the Burial*

However, the strong indication throughout the book is that he's doing alright for himself. He's accustomed to a pretty high standard of living and his idea of "not a very large salary" may differ a little from yours or mine.

> Slughorn took another deep draught from his mug, his eyes moving carefully around the cabin now, looking, Harry knew, for more treasures that he might be able to covert into a plentiful supply of oak-matured mead, crystallised pineapple and velvet smoking jackets.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.455 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 22, *After the Burial*

If you're asking me, I'd say probably enough to put you right in the middle of the middle class.

[Real world teachers in Britain apparently earn £22,023 (new qualified) to £32,187](http://www.prospects.ac.uk/secondary_school_teacher_salary.htm). I would imagine Slughorn's salary is right at the top end of this range in the wizarding world (adjusted for PPP and all the rest of it) - probably slightly more.

Another thing to consider is that Hogwarts teachers apparently get full bed and board for all the time they're teaching. What this means is that if you don't have any dependants, a large percentage of your salary is disposable income. Which means that Slughorn's salary probably goes a lot further towards his cushy lifestyle than the salary of a teacher who was married and with kids. So the fact that Slughorn seems to have quite a nice life may be related to how much of his money is his to spend on sweets and comfy chairs. He, also, of course, gets quite a lot of gifts from ex-students.

Comment: Definitely agreed that Slughorn's idea of his salary is probably skewed by his standard of living.

Comment: FYI, the teacher wages you quoted are the basic pay - it goes up further if you have years of experience or added responsibility. I would say Slughorn is eligible for both of those.

Comment: In particular, Slughorn's lifestyle seems a heck more expensive than McGonagall's. Even from a small salary, _she_ would probably manage to save up a significant amount over the years.

Comment: @leftaroundabout - Yes, Pottermore says that McGonagall used to have a house but now lives at Hogwarts, so that's a big saving. I imagine several of the teachers owned a property (or rented one) beyond the school even if they stayed there during term time (we know this is true of Snape) so McGonagall should certainly have more savings than most.

Comment: Heads of Houses (and deputy headmistress) probably draw additional income on top of teaching.

Answer (score 22):

The salary for professors at Hogwarts was never mentioned and the only salary that was, was the salary of Hit-Wizards. Now since Hit-Wizards are sent primarily against criminals (Aurors capture dark wizards not common criminals) they are the equivalent of police in our world.

According to payscale.com [a police officer's](http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Job=Police_Officer/Salary) average yearly salary is US $48,815 while [a professor's](http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Job=Professor,_Postsecondary_%2F_Higher_Education/Salary) average salary is $89,005 making it almost double a policeman's.

Now a Hit-Wizard trainee has a starting salary of 700 Galleons per month.

If you apply real world pay differences to the wizard world, Hogwarts professors would earn about 1500 Galleons.

Now since 1 Galleon = £5.00 (more or less US$9.75) it would bring their paycheck to $14,625 per month or $175,500 per year. On payscale.com they say professors can earn anywhere from $50K to $158K which would mean that Hogwarts professors are very well paid.

Comment: Where are Hit-Wizards mentioned?

Comment: It was mentioned as job offering in The Daily Prophet newsletters. I believe it was second one (Feb 8th 1999). Job offer was: "A trainee has a starting salary of 700 Galleons per month, a Ministry of Magic broomstick, and his or her own regular bed at St Mungo's"  This information can be found on Hit-Wizard page on official Harry Potter wiki as well

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic Nice find!

Comment: Note that your cited source's "Professor" is a post-secondary professor, meaning a tenured (or tenure-track) faculty member at a college or university.  Better matches from that site are high school teacher: $47k, secondary school teacher: $46k, and secondary school teacher (not not "special" or "vocational" education): $45k.  Worth noting that these people are paid less than the police officers you cite.

Comment: @Eric the qualifications to become a secondary school teacher are significantly lower than to become a Hogwarts teacher. Any decent magic wielder could perform the duties a Hit Wizard, just like any decent fit person could perform the duties of a police officer or a school teacher. The requirements to be on Hogwarts staff are much closer to (if not beyond!) a tenure-track professor than they are to school teachers.

Comment: @corsiKa : You'd hope that Hogwarts teachers would be the best people one could find, but there is a significant body of literature on the people actually hired to those positions and their many deficiencies and failings...

Comment: @VanjaVasiljevic That line is not the exact quote, it was a paraphrase of about a paragraph of text.

Comment: @Luke and others: Hit Wizards are actually mentioned in *The Prisoner of Azkaban* although that really makes them sound very highly-trained. "'You don't know what you're talking about, Hagrid,' said Fudge sharply. 'Nobody but trained Hit Wizards from the Magical Law Enforcement Squad would have stood a chance against Black once he was cornered. [...]'" (When Fudge, the teachers and Rosmerta were talking about Sirius and Pettigrew in The Hog's Head, from the chapter *The Marauder's Map*). I don't think they're just police, in fact I think they're probably the cream of the aurors

Comment: The second DP issue mentioned other salaries as well.

Answer (score 8):

The only salary mentioned in the books, that I remember, is the one that Dumbledore offered to Dobby. It was 10 galleons per week. We could accept this as the "minimal wage" of the Wizard's world.

Another point of reference is the 700 galleons won by Arthur Weasley - that is mentioned as a "grand prize". So that's at least several times more than the average salary in the economy.

Based on that - a teacher will get at least double the minimal wage as a starting salary. So about 80 to 100 galleons per month for fresh start teachers like Lupin, Lockhart or Hagrid is a reasonable assumption. Senior teachers like Snape or McGonnagal would get more - maybe up to 200.

Comment: Note that the to pprize in any contest may be referred to as the "grand prize". If you're playing in a charity Bingo tournament, the "grand prize" might be a small kitchen item, like a toaster.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing canon to that effect, however it is presumably relatively competitive as we see professors able to spend money on luxuries with no apparent worries. Furthermore, they are able to keep recruiting Defence Against the Dark Arts teachers for ***decades***, with a rate of one a year. This suggests that the pay is probably relatively high.

Sorry I can't be more thorough.

Comment: Pay for DADA teachers may be inflated, especially if the post is known to be literally cursed. Especially if Quirrell and Lockhart aren't the first to be killed or (functionally) crippled in the post.

Comment: @RDFozz Is it known to be cursed?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anyone considered that wizards world is a relatively small community. With the population of only 10000 - 12000 wizards in all Britain (http://www.seven-fifty.net/wizpop.htm), and the number of students go to school each year might only be 500 - 1000 students( https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Forum:Number_of_hogwarts_Students%3F). Let's say each student pay 20 - 50 galleons for books, robes, wands, etc. it would yield around 50,000 galleons / year for the school. Now the school has at least 12 professors (based on 12 subjects that Percy took for his NEWTs) or 14 since Hermione has to drop some subjects but still has 12 OWLs, plus the Headmaster and caretaker Filch, some substitute and optional classes teachers like Music or Alchemy, it would be around 18 - 20 staffs. 50,000 / 20 = 2,500 / year for one staff. Then you have to minus the amount of money necessary for equipment and materials for each class, like Student's Potion Store, or Sprout's classes plants, which would be around 1000 galleons, so that left the school with 49,000 a year, and 2,450 / year for one staff. Let's say the school was supported from the Minister, and then consider the Minister of Magic is also very small because the number of witches and wizards in England, so each staff would receive a third more of their salary earned from students fees 2,450 + (2,450/3) = 3,266.7 galleons / year. Divided for 12 months you would get 272.225 galleons/ month.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've done a lot of work here, but you really need to be able to cite some in-universe sources for a proper answer, otherwise it's just speculation.  Also, some of the existing answers do have actual numbers, so your answer shouldn't ignore or contradict those.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the in-universe evidences, you would see that there is even smaller number of students than speculations, because there are only Neville, Ron, Seamus and Dean mentioned in the book as Gryffindors sleeping in the same room as Harry. Yet the room named 'First Year Boy's Room', so there are only 5 Gryfffindors boys in Harry's year, and let's say the number of boys and girl are similar, so 10 Gryffindors in1991. Multiply for 4 houses would be 40 students and 7 years are 280 students in Hogwarts. But that would make the professors really poor, so I use speculations instead.

Comment: https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty. This is the list of the 40 students in Harry's year written by J.K.Rowling herself.

Comment: *"Let's say each student pay 20 - 50 galleons for books, robes, wands, etc. it would yield around 50,000 galleons / year for the school"* Students buy those items from shops in Diagon Alley, not from Hogwarts.

Comment: That's why it was just speculations, but the Diagon Alley shops would then eventually give taxes to The Ministry, so the money go back to Ministry to pay for Hogwarts. In Muggle world, the government collects tax from at least millions citizens, but the tax ministry of magic collects only about 13000 people, and not all of those would go in for education (they have to pay for Ministry employees, maybe some money go to Gringotts, fix the roads, Mungo Hospital, etc.). So unless their is an organization that let the ministry borrow money, the salary of professors would be low.