# How could McGonagall afford a Nimbus 2000 on a teacher's salary?

Tags: harry-potter

Seems like the best piece of equipment for a sport that is played professionally and has such a big public following probably costs quite a bit. Did McGonagall buy it in a private capacity or perhaps with funds available to her as head of house?

Comment: [Related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115732/58193).

Comment: Maybe she expensed it?

Comment: Are you *sure* McGonagall paid for it? dear old Albus could've and he just has Minerva deliver it to Harry.

Comment: How much does one cost?

Comment: How do you know it wasn't a funding project? Something like GoFundWitch?

Answer (score 0):

Teachers don't make a lot in the muggle world (married to one, trust me), but since her living expenses were essentially zero during the school year, maybe she felt she could afford to splash out her 9 months (approximately) of school year salary on a nice gift for *The Boy Who Lived™*. Especially since he was in her house.

Comment: Seems pretty much speculation to me. We're never told how much do magic teachers earn. They might be really well paid.

Comment: @Roberto https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115732/how-well-are-professors-paid-at-hogwarts

Comment: 'tis pure speculation, @Roberto, but if you look at the linked question, it's really not that far off. Especially since, as noted in that linked answer, room & board are covered for the period of time the professor is at school. (Though, one must assume that he's making mortgage/rent payments on her "permanent" non-school residence while at school).

Comment: Also, no more or less speculation than the answers on both of the linked questions.